# Deliminter is not working for scanner

Tags: java, delimiter

The user will enter a=(number here). I then want it to cut off the a= and retain the number. It works when I use s.next() but of course it makes me enter it two times which I don't want. With s.nextLine() I enter it once and the delimiter does not work. Why is this?

```
    Scanner s  = new Scanner(System.in);
    s.useDelimiter("a=");
    String n = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `nextLine()` doesn't care about delimiters.  The delimiters only affect `Scanner` when you tell it to return tokens.  `nextLine()` just returns whatever is left on the current line without caring about tokens.

A delimiter is not the way to go here; the purpose of delimiters is to tell the `Scanner` what can come *between* tokens, but you're trying to use it for a purpose it wasn't intended for.  Instead:

```
String n = s.nextLine().replaceFirst("^a=","");
```

This inputs a line, then strips off `a=` if it appears at the beginning of the string (i.e. it replaces it with the empty string `""`).  `replaceFirst` takes a regular expression, and `^` means that it only matches if the `a=` is at the beginning of the string.  This won't check to make sure the user actually entered `a=`; if you want to check this, your code will need to be a bit more complex, but the key thing here is that you want to use `s.nextLine()` to return a `String`, and then do whatever checking and manipulation you need on that `String`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a list of replacements. Say I wanted to do this for b= as well. Is there a way to do this on one line rather than listing out n.replaceFirst("^b=",""); n.replaceFirst("^c=",""); etc.. etc..

Comment: @Theunknown You may want to look over [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) on regular expressions.  For a simple case like you say, you could use `"^(a|b|c)="` or `"^[abc]="` as the regular expression.  The second one would work only with single letters.  If you want to save the text that appears before the `=`, there are other ways, either using regular expressions or other `String` methods.

Comment: I will definitely read into those tutorials. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `StringTokenizer` if `Scanner#useDelimiter()` is not suitable for your case.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String n = s.nextLine();
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(n, "a=");

while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

or try with `String#split()` method

```
for (String str : n.split("a=")) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

input:

```
a=123a=546a=78a=9
```

output:

```
123
546
78
9
```